# How to remove all lines from a large text file (>60GB) that contains a specific alphabet in python?

Tags: python

I have a large text file (>60GB) and I want to remove certain lines from it.

The text file contains:

```
352_0M, 352_1M,  0.913
500_1F, 452_0M,  0.500
870_0M, 400_1F,  0.980
601_1F, 470_0M,  0.630
845_0M, 900_1M,  0.456
100_1F, 250_0F,  0.123
...
```

I want to remove all lines containing the "F" alphabet in the first column or second column or both. The expected output is:

```
352_0M, 352_1M,  0.913
845_0M, 900_1M,  0.456
```

How to do this in python?

Comment: How about using a simple but specialized tool like `grep` instead of writing code?

Comment: `grep -v "F, " inputfile >outputfile`  With some extra effort, that can be made to be limited to the first two columns but it will work fine with the sample data.

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. See: [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with open('input_file','r') as inf:
    with open('output_file','w') as outf:
        for line in inf:
            if not any('F' in x for x in line.split(',', 2)[:2]):
                outf.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution with numpy

```
import numpy as np
A = np.loadtxt('input_file',dtype=str,delimiter=', ')
id1 = [ 'F' not in a for a in A.T[0]]
id2 = [ 'F' not in a for a in A.T[1]]
B = A[np.bitwise_and(id1,id2)]
np.savetxt('file_out',B)
```

EDIT: thanks to the comments of Marcos and AMC. I correct myself when I though my proposed solution was a bit faster: it is not! The solution of Błotosmętek is much better both for performance and for RAM usage. I checked with a test file of 600 GB and the proposed numpy solution is twice worse than the Błotosmętek's one.

Comment: you need to have more than 60GB of RAM for this.

Comment: _I think a bit faster than plain python_ For numerical operations on arrays, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Try to split the file into multiple parts with python, then search for the specific words. It is very difficult to process the large sized files because it requires huge RAM capacity.